# Why can't I append a Date to a list?

Tags: julia

Trying to append a `Date` or `DateTime` instance to a list results in a `MethodError`:

```
julia> v = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> myDate = Date(2018,2,12)
2018-02-12

julia> append!(v,myDate)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Date)
Closest candidates are:
length(::SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:256
length(::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:558
length(::MethodTable) at reflection.jl:634
```

Why is this, and how can one generate a dynamically-sized array of Dates with this limitation?

Comment: `help?> append!` take a look at ` append!` 's docstrings. Since `Date(2018,2,12)` is not a collection, you should use `push!(v,myDate)` or `append!(v,[myDate])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the doc (`?push!` and `?appned!`) you must use `push!` to add an individual element. `append!` applies to collections

```
julia> v = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> myDate = Date(2018,2,12)
2018-02-12

julia> push!(v,myDate)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 2018-02-12

julia> append!(v,[myDate myDate myDate])
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 2018-02-12
 2018-02-12
 2018-02-12
 2018-02-12
```